# why put '!' at the beginning of a line of code google colab ML model?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

```
! chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
```

why put '!' at the beginning of a line of code google colab ML model?

i want to know why this is so

Comment: Code should be included as text in the body of your question itself; content that's only behind links does not count as included in the question itself for purposes of determining whether it's answerable, for the reasons given in [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @AhmedAEK, wouldn't it have been just as easy to retype the line of code from the image rather than making it inline but leaving it as an image? (I've now done that myself)

Answer (score 0):

This indicates it is running a shell command. For instance, you can install packages by

```bash
!pip install
```

within Google Colab.

Comment: thanks! tell please How can I get a list of these commands?

Comment: @Azizbek it's not a fixed set of available commands; it depends on which software is installed.

Comment: i.e. can I use all shell commands in my notebook(google collab)?